# Custom activity backstack - app closes when relaunching

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have some specific requirements to be implemented in my app. This is some sort of setup before using the app. The activities should go like this:

A -> B or C -> D -> E-> F ... etc.

Application always starts at A, then goes to B or C. But if during previous launches something was set in latter activities the custom stack is being built and everything runs from the latest not set activity (with the possibility to navigate back like this:

(D and E were already configured)

A->B or C -> F and then going back to E -> D.

When in D, on another back button press I am supposed to close app.

This all works fine.

However I lately noticed though that if I leave the app in D, and start it again from the launcher the application does not open. In logs nothing really happens, only thing I see is my custom view in Activity A reports "onDetachedFromWindow" callback. No Activity report any other action although I don't have lifecycle callbacks logged.

The click on a launcher icon is received as the sound effect pops.

When I click again it all starts properly from activity A again.

Now the code:

Excerpt from the manifest - names changes to match above example, irrelevant stuff cut off:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.A"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:taskAffinity="A"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.G"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.B"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

    <activity 
        android:name=".ui.C"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.D"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.E"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.F"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoTitle"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Backstack creation:

```
public static TaskStackBuilder getSetupTaskStack(final Activity activity, final Config partialConfig) {
    final TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(activity);

    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(activity, D.class));
    if (partialConfig == null || partialConfig.getD() == null) {
        return taskStackBuilder;
    }

    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(activity, E.class));
    if (partialConfig.getE() == null) {
        return taskStackBuilder;
    }

    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(activity, F.class));
    if (partialConfig.getF() == null) {
        return taskStackBuilder;
    }

    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(activity, G.class));
    if (partialConfig.getG()==null) {
        return taskStackBuilder;
    }

    final Intent mainActivityIntent = MainActivity.getActivityIntent(activity);

    return TaskStackBuilder.create(activity).addNextIntent(mainActivityIntent);
}
```

The Activities do not have the *onBackPressed()* overriden.

I tried using parameters:
[clearOnTaskLaunch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) and [finishOnTaskLaunch](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish) but I am not entirely sure if they can help in here at all as I am not really sure what is happening with the activities in here.

The backstack creation happens in B or C when figuring out which activity should be launched. Then it is simply launched with *startActivities()*

Comment: Why does your launcher `Activity` have `excludeFromRecents="true"`? Why does your launcher `Activity` have `taskfAffinity="A"`? You are making a lot of trouble for yourself by setting these things.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that removing these makes things work correctly. However If I would like to keep those, then how should I handle this?

Comment: Please explain why you would want to keep those settings. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This was part of legacy code that was eventually removed. Thank you for guiding towards right direction.